# Taking a time derivative of a function of 3 variables.

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

I have a function of $3$ variables which are all functions of $t$.

$$x = \frac{v_1t-y}{\sqrt{(v_2/\dot{x})^2 -1}} \tag 1 $$

In the equation $v_1,v_2$ are constant and $x$ and $y$ are both function of $t$ (also $\dot{x}$ is $\frac{dx}{dt}$). I am trying to differentiate $(1)$ with respect to $t$, but I am not sure how to do this as there are three variables and an $\dot{x}$ already. I tried holding $x,y$ constant but that instinctively does not make sense as these change with respect to $t$.

Comment: You have to use the chain rule. How would you for example differentiate if it were just $\dot x$?

Comment: I am not sure :(

Comment: When you say differentiate, are you trying to find $\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}$, or $\frac{dx}{dt}$?  The answers are different.

Comment: The second one.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

If $y(t)$ and $\dot{x}(t)$ are two functions independent from $x(t)$
 you can use quotient rule and chain rule.

If $\dot{x}=\dfrac{dx}{dt}$, as I suppose, you have not a function but a differential equation that you can manipulate formally solving for $\dot{x}$ and find:
$$
\dot{x}=\dfrac{dx}{dt}=F(t,x(t),y(t))=\dfrac{v_2x}{\sqrt{(v_1t-y)+x^2}}
$$
But it seems not simple to solve.

Comment: So I can differentiate it normally using the quotient rule?

Comment: Yes, it is a bit intricate but it works.

Comment: @curo: My first answer was wrong . I've edit.

Answer (score 0):

I would first square both sides of the equation to get rid of the square root in the denominator:

$$x^{2}=\frac {(v_{1}t-y)^{2}}{(\sqrt{(\frac {v_{2}}{\dot{x}})^{2}-1})^{2}}$$

$$x^{2}=\frac {v_{1}^{2}t^{2}-2v_{1}ty+y^{2}}{(\frac {v_{2}}{\dot{x}})^{2}-1}$$

Then rearrange it this way:

$$((\frac {v_{2}}{\dot{x}})^{2}-1)x^{2}=v_{1}^{2}t^{2}-2v_{1}ty+y^{2}$$

$$\frac {v_{2}^{2}x^{2}}{\dot{x}^{2}}-x^{2}=v_{1}^{2}t^{2}-2v_{1}ty+y^{2}$$

$$\frac {v_{2}^{2}x^{2}-x^{2}\dot{x}^{2}}{\dot{x}^{2}}=v_{1}^{2}t^{2}-2v_{1}ty+y^{2}$$

$$v_{2}^{2}x^{2}-x^{2}\dot{x}^{2}=(v_{1}^{2}t^{2}-2v_{1}ty+y^{2})\dot{x}^{2}$$

$$v_{2}^{2}x^{2}=(v_{1}^{2}t^{2}-2v_{1}ty+y^{2})\dot{x}^{2}+x^{2}\dot{x}^{2}$$

$$v_{2}^{2}x^{2}=(v_{1}^{2}t^{2}-2v_{1}ty+y^{2}+x^{2})\dot{x}^{2}$$

$$\dot{x}^{2}=\frac {v_{2}^{2}x^{2}}{v_{1}^{2}t^{2}-2v_{1}ty+y^{2}+x^{2}}$$

$$\dot{x}=\sqrt \frac {v_{2}^{2}x^{2}}{v_{1}^{2}t^{2}-2v_{1}ty+y^{2}+x^{2}}$$

$$\dot{x}=\frac {v_{2}x}{\sqrt{v_{1}^{2}t^{2}-2v_{1}ty+y^{2}+x^{2}}}$$

$$\dot{x}=\frac {dx}{dt}=\frac {v_{2}x}{\sqrt{(v_{1}t-y)^{2}+x^{2}}}$$

This would be your answer since $\dot{x}=\frac {dx}{dt}$, hope I helped:)